# Returning a function for the outside function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't know this is possible, but I have some special situations requiring it.

```
//Obj is a class with nothing.
Obj.prototype.v1 = function(){
    //this is a normal statement.
    //it could be something else
    return 3;
}
//or it can be any way to declare a function: 
var v1 = function(){return 3};

Obj.prototype.v2 = function(){
    return this.v1()+2;
}
```

How to make it directly returns 3 here? It's like the function v1() is something like pseudocode `this.return(3)` for v2(), and certainly nothing can be reached after the first return.

If I'm generating the code dynamically and it has to be a return in the second function. (So it can easily get unexpected token for `return (return 3).v2()`, while trying to get the inside function to be called behaving like it's part of current function.)

Is there anyway to make `this.v1()` directly cause outside function `v2()` to return, for the first return it encounters? Preferably by focusing on modifying v1().

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. I don't know what "tag of String with function value" means. You want to *make WHAT directly returns 3 here*? Which *first return* are you referring to? What do you mean by *generating the code dynamically*? Why would code such as `return (return 3).v2()` ever be generated or executed?

Comment: Even I am unclear with what you are asking.

Comment: Modified, it's generated as 'return this.v1() +2', this statement is correct, unless we need v1() to cause a direct return, then I tried to reveal v1() from the scope of current function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to make this.v1() directly cause outside function v2() to return, for the first return it encounters?

The idiomatic solution is to express this logic in `v2`. For example, you could cause `v1` to modify a flag that decides what `v2` does:

```
Obj.prototype.v1 = function(){
    this.v1.continue = true;  /* XXX: Continue? */
    this.v1.continue = false; /* ...  or not?   */
    return 3;
}

Obj.prototype.v2 = function(){
    var ret_val = this.v1()+2;
    if (!this.v1.continue) {
        return;
    }
    /* XXX: Insert more code here */
}
```

We're talking about rather basic JavaScript here. Do you have a book?

> Preferably by focusing on modifying v1().

I'm sure it's possible to circumvent the control of execution that `v2` has when `v1` returns in *some* situations, but that doesn't make it a good idea. Think about how difficult it'll become to debug this code!

For example, you could `throw` an error which `v2` doesn't catch, and catch it further upstream. Such a hideous abuse of `throw` would be worse than the abuse of `goto`! Don't modify your code flow in such an unclear manner; it makes maintenance and debugging a nightmare!

Comment: Hi Seb, the function v2 you wrote still doesn't return because of the calling of v1. I'm saying this because I'm trying to make it return 3 before plus 2.